# Set attributes of tags of HTML using JSoup

Tags: java, html, tags, jsoup

How to set attributes of tags of HTML using JSoup?

I want to set the attribute->"src" of tag->"img"  in Java using Jsoup Library.

```
Elements img_attributes = doc.select("img[src^=/im]");
for(Element img_attribute: img_attributes)
{

String s = img_attribute.attr("src");
System.out.println(s);
}
```

This code prints the `src` values.
I want to change the `src` values.

Comment: @TechSpellBound : here the details http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Have you tried something like this `Elements.attr(String key, String value)`?

Answer (score 10):

You cen do this with `attr()` method in both ways: loop or directly on the `Elements` object:

```
// In a loop
for( Element img : doc.select("img[src]") )
{
    img.attr("src", "your-source-here"); // set attribute 'src' to 'your-source-here'
}

// Or directly on the 'Elements'
doc.select("img[src]").attr("src", "your-value-here");
```

In fact both solutions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

check 
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 
i think function

```
public Element attr(String attributeKey,
                    String attributeValue)
```

is useful for you

Answer (score -2):

Please modify it and write it into your html file through **doc**.